# how to create, then format, a volume with an NTFS filesystem?

Tags: windows, winapi, format, ntfs

What is the preferred way to create a partition and then format an NTFS volume within this volume?

I'd prefer to stick with the Win32 API, instead of using WMI or a script

is this possible?  any clues to the API's/IOCTLs?  (an example would be great)

thanks!