# WIN API: Creating disk partition

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

need to format a USB drive using the WIN32 API, and I've got as far as creating a partition at the correct size but the format shows up as RAW. I am passing PARTITION_IFS (NTFS) as part of my info structs however as I said it's still showing up as RAW.
Here's the code

```
const PARTITION_STYLE gptMbr = args.useUefi ? PARTITION_STYLE_GPT : PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;
    
    //const TCHAR driveLetter[] = { _T('\\'), _T('\\'), _T('.'), _T('\\'), args.driveLabel, (':'), _T('\0') };
    const TCHAR driveLetter[] = "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE4";
    HANDLE drive = CreateFile(driveLetter, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    if (drive == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return FERR_CANT_OPEN_DRIVE;
    
    // Close handle on exit
    ScopeExit exit([&drive]() { 
        CloseHandle(drive); 
    });

    CREATE_DISK diskArgs;
    memset(&diskArgs, 0, sizeof(CREATE_DISK));
    CREATE_DISK_MBR dskMbr = { 0 };
    dskMbr.Signature = 1;
    diskArgs.PartitionStyle = gptMbr;
    diskArgs.Mbr = dskMbr;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(drive, IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK, &diskArgs, sizeof(diskArgs), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL))
        return FERR_FORMAT_FAILURE;

    // listen for MSR partition arrival if using GPT
    if (args.useUefi)
    { 
        
    }

    // drive size
    GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION lenInfo = { 0 };
    if (!DeviceIoControl(drive, IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO, NULL, 0, &lenInfo, sizeof(lenInfo), NULL, NULL))
        return FERR_FORMAT_FAILURE;
    
    const size_t nLayoutBytes = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) + sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX) * 3;
    DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX* layout = (DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX*)malloc(nLayoutBytes);
    memset(layout, 0, nLayoutBytes);
    layout->PartitionStyle = gptMbr;
    layout->PartitionCount = 1;
    layout->Mbr.Signature = diskArgs.Mbr.Signature;

    PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX& partition = layout->PartitionEntry[0];
    partition.PartitionStyle = gptMbr;
    partition.StartingOffset.QuadPart = 0;
    partition.PartitionLength.QuadPart = lenInfo.Length.QuadPart; //3221225472;
    partition.PartitionNumber = 1;
    partition.RewritePartition = TRUE;
    partition.IsServicePartition = FALSE;

    partition.Mbr.PartitionType = PARTITION_IFS;
    partition.Mbr.BootIndicator = FALSE;
    partition.Mbr.RecognizedPartition = TRUE;
    partition.Mbr.HiddenSectors = 0;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(drive, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, layout, nLayoutBytes, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL))
        return FERR_FORMAT_FAILURE;

    return FERR_OK;
```

If anyone is familiar with the windows API and knows why it might not be being formatted in the correct format, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479087/how-to-create-then-format-a-volume-with-an-ntfs-filesystem) have partially rotted away, but at least it can provide you with some search keywords for your research. Short version: so far you have only manipulated the partition table, you still need another request to create the file system.

Comment: You forgot to format the partition. This used to be done via [`IVdsAdvancedDisk::FormatPartition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vds/nf-vds-ivdsadvanceddisk-formatpartition), which has been superseded by the [Windows Storage Management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/windows-storage-management-api-portal). I don't know how to use the latter (or even make sense out of the documentation).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589494/deviceiocontrol-to-initialize-and-create-a-ntfs-partition

Comment: Interesting that you specify a format for IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, but have to use a separate function to actually format it.. I'm gonna need to figure out how to get the volume label from the physical drive

Comment: There is a sample [StorageManagement](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/StorageManagement) of *Windows Storage Management API*. Does it work for you?

Comment: I'm getting an AV at line 1191 in that sample when trying to use pInstance

Comment: The instance of the storage pool we create is null.. The GetElement call in GetCreatedInstance reports an OK code but the instance is null